# Regex negative look ahead of two consecutive space characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture this string using the regular expression below. I am having trouble distinguishing between "ISO Country Symbol" and "ISO_country_symbol". Essentially, I want to capture "2", "ISO Country Symbol" and "ISO_country_symbol". Also, group capturing "ISO_country_symbol" never contains any spaces.

I appreciate any hint

Regex:

```
(\#)\s+(\d+)\s+([\w\s]+(?!\s{2,}))\s+(\w+)\s+\w+
```

String:

```
#  2 ISO Country Symbol                ISO_country_symbol             S   3  0
```

Comment: What is the escape `\#` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than repeating a group with a negative lookahead, it would probably be easier to repeat *lazily* and require that the the group be followed by at least two spaces. That is, to match just the `ISO Country Symbol`, you could use

```
(\w[\w\s]+?\w)\s{2,}
```

Full pattern:

```
(\#)\s+(\d+)\s+(\w[\w\s]+?\w)\s{2,}(\w+)\s+\w+
```

https://regex101.com/r/MDUI3B/1

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-greedy match and require at least two spaces after it.

Example (Python):

```
>>> s = '#  2 ISO Country Symbol                ISO_country_symbol             S   3  0'
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'#\s+(\d+)\s+([\w\s]+?)\s{2,}(\w+)',s).groups()
('2', 'ISO Country Symbol', 'ISO_country_symbol')
```